# Как проверить возможность выводить звук с ip камеры?

Tags: python, ip, камера, web-camera

Многие камеры поддерживают возможность вывода с них звука через встроенный динамик. Как проверить поддерживает ли данную возможность камера имея ее ip, логин и пароль?

Comment: Подозреваю, что у каждой камеры будет свой собственный протокол и универсальный способ вряд ли существует

Comment: iVMS 4000 как-то же может выводить с многих камер

Comment: Неправда, iVMS 4000 поддерживает только камеры hikvision. Если вас интересуют только камеры hikvision и никакие другие — допишите соответствующее уточнение в текст вопроса

Comment: Спасибо, не знал